# GetTestResultsAsync returns null while pure REST API call returns expected values

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using NuGet package: Team Foundation Server.Client (16.143.1) for a .NET console app, specifically Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.TestManagement.WebAPI.

In the console app, I'm expecting GetTestResultsAsync to return a ShallowReference to TestSuite that is not null but it returns as null:

```
var testResults = await _testClient.GetTestResultsAsync(
                            project: _teamProject,
                            detailsToInclude: ResultDetails.WorkItems,
                            runId: testRunId,
                            skip: skip,
                            top: BatchSize);
```

Most other fields populate as expected but TestSuite is always null, regardless of if I include detailsToInclude or not.

However, when calling the equivalent REST API call in a web browser, I can see the testSuite object with id and name properties filled in correctly.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/1000268/results/100000?api-version=5.0
```

Expected response (REST):

```
{"id":"1000268","name":"Test (Manual)"..."testCaseTitle":"test","testCaseRevision":1,"testPlan":{"id":"28"},"testSuite":{"id":"1049","name":"Test"}...}
```

Actual response (SDK):

```
id: 1000268
name: Test (Manual)
testSuite: null
```

I can confirm the test cases that the test results reference are in test suites. How can I fix this? Or do I need to call using REST instead of the SDK in my console app?

Comment: If you remove all the parameters unless Team project and Test run id, did you get the suite?

Comment: No luck :( It actually looks like I seem similar behavior with the AssociatedBugs property, hmm...

Comment: I get also the Suite with the SDK :/ (in TFS 2018)

Comment: Oh weird so it works for you? I'll have to keep testing different combinations as I can get what I'm looking for when using the browser for the REST call but just not from the SDK. Thanks for at least checking on your instance, maybe there's a weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/1000268/results/100000?api-version=5.0
```

The rest api you are using is used to get test results for a test run, and can't get properties about test suites.

To get the id and name properties about the test suites you should use this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20suites%20for%20plan?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites?api-version=5.0
```

Below is the response I got with this rest api.
[image]

Comment: The Test Results API returns a shallow reference for TestSuit (name, ID) which shows up in the REST call (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/Results/Get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) but doesn't show up in the .NET SDK wrapper for the same call.